# Node.js Implementation of JSON.parse

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, security, v8

I need to get javascript object from untrusted json.

Initially it comes as string and there are two ways of doing the task: `eval()` and `JSON.parse()`.

Where I can see Node.js implementation of `JSON.parse`, because I'm afraid that it uses eval under the hood and there can be security gaps.

I was trying to check `v8` repo and even tried `Function.prototype.toSource()` in Firefox - no result.

Can anybody provide me with some proofs that I shouldn't worry to use it ?

Comment: "because I'm afraid that it uses eval under the hood and there can be security gaps" — That doesn't seem like a *reasonable* fear to have. It's a major software project, which is used by vast numbers of people, and gets a lot of pen testing.

Comment: "Where I can see Node.js implementation of JSON.parse," — It doesn't have one. It gets it from the underlying JS engine (of which there are more than one (including V8 and ChakraCore))

Comment: you can use an open source JSON library.

Comment: „I was trying to check v8 repo […]“ You should have done so too. The source code for the JSON.parse implementation in v8 is here: https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/master/src/json-parser.cc

Comment: does C lang guarantees that dangerous code wouldn't executed ?

Comment: @EnthusiasticDeveloper — No. It is very easy to write dangerous code in C. If you want to reassure yourself that Google are not publishing a `JSON.parse` function which has security flaws then you'll need to learn enough about C to perform a security audit of their code.

Answer (score 3):

V8 developer here. `JSON.parse` does not use `eval` under the hood -- that's precisely the point of having `JSON.parse`, and why it's strongly recommended to use that (rather than `eval`) for parsing JSON data.

As feeela already pointed out, if you want to verify this yourself, look at the source: https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/master/src/json-parser.cc

Or run an experiment:

```
var bad_json_data = 'console.log("executed!"); "{foo:1}"';
var o1 = eval(bad_json_data);  // Prints to console.
var o2 = JSON.parse(bad_json_data);  // SyntaxError!
```

That said, you always have to be careful with untrusted input. Using `JSON.parse` to convert the JSON string to an object is safe, but afterwards you still have to be careful what you're using that object for (as one random example, its property values could still allow SQL injection attacks if you try to store them in a database).

Comment: Dear V8 developer, please tell whether JSON parser uses regular expressions? Is it subject to ReDoS attacks?

Comment: No, the JSON parser does not use regular expressions under the hood. Even if it did, my understanding is that ReDoS attacks usually require the *attacker* to supply a malicious regexp; so any builtin in any environment can happily use regexps internally without being susceptible to such attacks, as long as those built-in regexps are safe/well-behaved.

Answer (score -2):

You cannot parse Functions/Classes as JSON. And if there are functions they would be represented as strings. You can check that if u try:

```js
const obj = {
  a: () => console.log("test")
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(obj))
// prints {}
```

Comment: "You cannot parse Functions/Classes as JSON" — That isn't what the question is about.